# Restored DB Server Using FQDN Causing Distribution Issues

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, replication, configuration

We had a complete RAID failure on one of our SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 servers.  I setup a new server and restored everything and we're basically up and running again. But, I have one small issue: I am trying to restore the publications/subscriptions and I keep running in to errors with the server name.

It seems in my haste to get things back up and running I used the FQDN instead of the Netbios name somewhere.  If I do `SELECT @@SERVERNAME`, I get the netbios name ('KAI') but if I do an `sp_helpservers` then I see the FQDN ('kai.caymanport.com') for both the name and networkname fields.

How can I correct this or can I correct this?  I already tried to do a `sp_dropserver`, `sp_addserver 'KAI', LOCAL` (which worked) but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1, once your run the sp_Drop/addserver, most likely the system needs a start up if there is no other issues. You may also put the downtime into your consideration.

2, If the problem is still there after restarting your server, you may disable the connection between your replica serves, restore each one individually, then set the replication on your new server .

3, You may also experience issues if your SP is old, refer to Microsoft for SP new release.

Thank you,

Comment: Yes, as I thought, restarting the SQL service this morning fixed the problem.  Thanks.